# What's is "this" refer to in Phaser 3?

Tags: javascript, oop, this, phaser-framework

I'm new to Javascript and want to make simple games with Phaser 3, and I found that Javascript seems to be a little different from other OOP languages like C++ or Java. I checked out the tutorial in the official website and some other tutorial page, most of the code is like:

```
var config = {
    ...
    scene: {
        preload: preload,
        create: create,
        update: update
    }
}
var game = new Phaser.Game(config)

function preload(){
    this.load.img(...)
}
```

My question is what is the ‍`"this"` in the `preload()` indicate to? Is it means the `"game"` we defined before?

And how to check the object's class in console? `typeof()` only tells `"object"`.

Comment: Take a look at https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_invocation.asp. It explained `this` concept simple

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Answer (score 5):

`this` is an instance of `Phaser.Scene` and not `Phaser.Game`.
The other answers are incorrect. The code is running the browser.

To see the docs for a `Scene` you can look [here](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Scene.html)

Answer (score 2):

In the code you have `this` is a pointer to your game instance which is why you can call Phaser methods to load assets, adjust the camera, etc.

In your config you are setting which function is called during the preload step in the game.  When Phaser runs it calls your function (which just happens to be named `preload` too) and sets the scope of `this` to the game instance.

Comment: This assignment of `this` happens kind of implicitly in this case because Phaser's orchestration happens behind the scenes, you don't "see" the caller of `preload` in your custom code other than defining it as something Phaser can call in the `config`.